# How to make clickable a part of UIView

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a custom view with stackview inside. In my stack view contains Image, Label1, and Label2 horizontally.
I set my custom view with constraints with height = 25 and width = 160.
I need to tap only on a specific part of the view. How can I do it?

For example, only Label2 can be clickable.[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(click))
    label2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label2.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
 
}


@objc func click(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use GestureRecognizers https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures